# What acid can remove Calcium in Ca2SiO4 to leave SiO2 (mostly)

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

What acid can remove calcium in $\ce{Ca2SiO4}$ to leave $\ce{SiO2}$ (mostly)?

It seems that calcium silicate is stable in most acids, but I need to etch it and leave only silica (mostly).